# VBScript List all Windows Services by user "Log on As"

Tags: windows, service, vbscript, filtering

I need help, how to create script (VB) listing all Services Windows in the computers in TXT file (Using wmi I think better), but I'd like know how to filter by "Log On As" because all customized Services running specify user.

Thank you for everybody.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
for each item in GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2").ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE StartName = 'LocalSystem'",,48) 
    Wscript.Echo item.Name + "/" + item.StartName
next
```